# Exception during databinding generation after upgrading to gradle plugin 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-databinding, gradle-plugin

I upgraded a project to Gradle plugin 3.0.1, but during the databinding classes generation, I get the following error (and the binding classes are not generated):

```
error: cannot generate view binders java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.getMatchingMultiAttributeSetters(SetterStore.java:642)
        at android.databinding.tool.store.SetterStore.getMultiAttributeSetterCalls(SetterStore.java:529)
        at android.databinding.tool.BindingTarget.resolveMultiSetters(BindingTarget.java:221)
        at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.<init>(LayoutBinder.java:249)
        at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.<init>(DataBinder.java:52)
        at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.ensureDataBinder(CompilerChef.java:90)
        at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:203)
        at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:193)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
        ...
```

After some investigation, it seems that the binding class is correctly generated if I have at most 1 attribute using data binding on a given element in a layout xml. If I add a second one, I get the previous exception.

In the context of my project, the following view causes the error, but unfortunately, in a brand new project, it compiles normally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="title"
            type="String"/>

        <variable
            name="visible"
            type="boolean"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- with either text or visiblility, the project builds, but not with both -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{title}"
            android:visibility="@{visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Has anyone encountered this issue ?